# Visual Studio Migration 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfsbuild

We have around 100 projects in our solution built on Visual studio 2008. We migrated projects to Visual studio 2015. After migration, when  the build is  triggered to  TFS build server,  we are getting the below error:

> "The type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace" (are you
>   missing an assembly reference)

Also note that the Build server has Visual studio 2012.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the type that VS cannot find to see if the appropriate reference is still there?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I can build the solution locally but get error when triggering build to TFS server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the environment on the build agent are **as same as** your local developer machine.

Since you can build the solution locally with VS2015 successfully, suggest you also install VS2015 on you build agent and try it again. (To make the environment clean, you can uninstall VS2012 first)